# How to customize column colors and shapes in antd chart library?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using column charts given in antd chart library. I understand how customization works and how I can change the color of column giving the fill prop. However if I have two columns grouped together like in this example, how do I specify different colors for both? I also want to give some border radius to the columns, any chance I can do that too?

Here is the antd reference
https://charts.ant.design/zh-CN/demos/column/#%E5%88%86%E7%BB%84%E6%9F%B1%E7%8A%B6%E5%9B%BE

And the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/5fshy

TIA

Answer (score 6):

You can use the color and colorField options to set custom colors as defined in the API documentation https://charts.ant.design/demos/column/?type=api#color

working snippet:

```
     var config = {
       data: props.data,
       xField: 'x',
       yField: 'y',
       seriesField: 'type',
       isPercent: true,
       isStack: true,
       meta: {
          value: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
         },
       },
       label: {
       position: 'middle',
       content: function content(item) {
          return ''.concat(item.y.toFixed(2), '%');
       },
       style: { fill: '#000' },
       },
       colorField: 'type', // or seriesField in some cases
       color:['#19CDD7','#DDB27C'],
      };
     return <Column {...config} />;
    }
```

For radius use the columnStyle parameter:

```
     columnStyle: {
       radius: [20, 20, 0, 0],
     },
```

Comment: is it possible to define the colors in the data prop? This would be handy if the color of each item in data is defined there already

Comment: @nerdess there has to be a way to declare the color in the data prop, did you find it out?

Comment: @Amr I did not find a way. So I created a separate array for the color that matches the order of the stuff in the data array. It actually makes sense that it is not mixed because then you have a clear separation of concerns between data and design.